# Does aws or datadog monitor long-lived resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, resources, devops, monitor

Got some accounts that should be monitored for long-lived resources that may have been abandoned, does anyone know if aws or datadog etc...do that? thanks

Comment: How would a monitoring service make the determination that something is abandoned?

Comment: hmm thats a good question, I have no idea lol

Comment: I'm going to say probably not unless there is some technical metric in which can be used to determine abandoned. There is tooling that help you keep track of resources with the help of resource tagging, but it's often a major effort to get legacy systems tagged.

Comment: I would take a look at the AWS billing dashboard pages. That's a free way that i've often used to find resources that should have been deleted.